# Cassandra internode security kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster over Kubernetes deployed as stateful sets.  Is it possible to implement security in Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In your Docker entrypoint use `sed` to inject whichever auth classes you wish to use:

```
sed -i "s/authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer/authorizer: ${AUTHORIZER_CLASS}/" ${CASSANDRA_CONF}/cassandra.yaml
sed -i "s/authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator/authenticator: ${AUTHENTICATOR_CLASS}/" ${CASSANDRA_CONF}/cassandra.yaml
```

This will create the default cassandra/cassandra role, which you can use to create your new roles.

> what about Cassandra Client-to-node encryption?

That's a little trickier.  Basically, you need to inject the certificate or keystore and the keystore's password into your image (from a password/secret store or other secure location).  Then, your entrypoint should add/update the following [standard SSL settings](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureSSLClientToNode.html) to the end of the `cassandra.yaml`:

```
if [ "${SSL_ENABLED}" == "true" ]; then
cat << EOF >> ${CASSANDRA_CONF}/cassandra.yaml
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: ${SSL_ENABLED}
    optional: ${SSL_OPTIONAL}
    keystore: ${CASSANDRA_CONF}/server-keystore.jks
    keystore_password: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
EOF
fi
```

If you also require two-way SSL (will need `require_client_auth: true` set) or Node-to-Node encryption, you'll also need to inject or build a Java truststore in the same manner.

Comment: And what about Cassandra Client-to-node encryption?

Comment: @SudipManandhar Edit made.  In the future, please ask only one question per question, and explicitly state what you are having trouble with.  Simply asking about "security" can mean several different things.